# Angular Animations and Phonegap not running on mobile

Tags: animation, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I've added a few ng-view animations (angular v 1.1.5) to a phonegap app.  They work great in the browser when testing both using ripple and when pointing the mobile phone's browser (android chrome in this case) to the app online, but when installed with phonegap, the animations do not run.   I'm not sure if the issue is with phonegap or with angular.  At first I thought it was just animating too fast so I slowed them down to 1.5s but it made no change in the app.

Is this a phone gap issue, an angular issue and/or how can we use these?

CSS defined animation:

```
.view-enter, .view-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
}

.view-enter {
  opacity:0;

}
.view-enter.view-enter-active {

  opacity:1;
}

.view-leave {

  opacity:1;
}
.view-leave.view-leave-active {
  left:-100px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Again these work great in the phone's browser, just not when it is inside the phonegap app.  Using Adobe build to build the app.  I also am fetching the css and displaying on the page just to confirm the actual css file is included in the phonegap build (it is).

Per one of the user's comments, here is the HTML.  The rest is handled by angular's default animations.  They work fine when run in a browser but not when run inside phonegap.  The routing works, the ng-view is changed, but the animation never occurs.

```
   <div class="container-fluid" id="viewer" ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'view-enter', leave: 'view-leave'}" >


     </div>
```

Tested on Nexus 4.

Comment: What platform ? IOS or Android ?

Comment: I ended up using a pre-made css solution - 
http://daneden.me/animate/
Works fantastic on IOS at least.

Comment: @AdamWare I was testing it on Android 4.2, specifically a nexus 4.

Comment: I am also struggling with this problem on Android.  I can confirm that this is a Angular `ng-animate` specific problem as when I set the ng-class in code the animation works in Android.

Comment: I was never able to get the angular animations to work.  Perhaps it has to do with the embedded browser that android uses and its support for the css animations.

Comment: I have tested this http://www.yearofmoo.com/nganimate-css3/ and it works on Chrome on Android 4.2

Comment: By the way, you should add more code and not just css if you want to get some answer.

Comment: @notme it works fine on chrome in android. it does not work when the exact code set is run inside a phonegap app. I'll add the HTML markup that is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely an issue with Android 4.2's stock browser. The first clue is that it works fine on desktop and in Chrome, but not in Phonegap -- InAppBrowser uses Android's stock browser.

Support for animations (and HTML5 in general) was pretty terrible in Android 4.2. Here's a [handy rundown](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android-4.2.html) of those quirks.

Hopefully you've been able to upgrade your Android version since June!

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) (works with Cordova) or [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) as paths to speed up all manner of browser-related slowness when deploying on older Android.